# Unable to connect to Oracle datable using ROracle on Linux (error ORA-01804, able to using Sql*Plus)

Tags: r, linux, database, oracle, roracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle using ROracle. I am able to using Sql*Plus from the terminal (on Linux), but using the following code in R:

```
 library(ROracle)
 drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
```

I get the error:

```
 Error in .oci.Driver(.oci.drv(), interruptible = interruptible, unicode_as_utf8 = unicode_as_utf8, :
 Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
```

I am using RStudio version 3.2.5.

My connection to the Oracle database is local. My environment variables are set in a profile permanently, so they shouldn't have to be set explicitly again. But, to be safe, I did set them explicitly again using:

```
 Sys.setenv()
```

Unsurprisingly, this didn't help.

I'm not really sure where to even begin, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Edit: I'm also aware that the ORA-01804 error is related to a time zone reading issue. So, I tried setting the

```
 NLS_LANG=en_US.UTF8
```

after initiating SQL*Plus and executing

```
 !echo $LANG
```

which gave me the NLS_LANG parameter. This now gives me the ORA-12715 error:

```
 ORA-12715:invalid character set specified
```

which suggests that the NLS_LANG parameter is incorrect. I've tried using a variety of different combinations of UTF-8, en, US, American, America, English, etc., but none seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this ORA-01804 error on Mac. You have to start R from within the instant client directory if you launch R from the command line. So first do:

```
cd /path/to/instantclient_11_2
```

To avoid this error in RStudio go to Tools > Global Options and change the default working directory to the instant client directory:

[image]

Note that using `setwd("/path/to/instantclient_11_2")` in R worked when launching R from the command line but not in RStudio.

By the way, it was not necessary for me to export ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by following [Oracle's instruction on Installing RStudio Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57012_01/doc.141/e57007/apx_rstudio.htm#BABIEAIE).

Edit the configuration file .Renviron. Supply the value of `ORACLE_HOME`. For example, using the BASH shell:

```
cd ~
sudo vi .Renviron
    ORACLE_HOME=ORACLE_HOME

export ORACLE_HOME
```

Notes:

- when running `Sys.getenv()`, I was only missing the `ORACLE_HOME` env variable. If you're also missing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you might need to add `rsession-ld-library-path=RHOME/lib:ORACLE_HOME/lib` to `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf`.
- you might also need `ORACLE_HOSTNAME` and `ORACLE_SID` depending on your database